# modify_shared_link_settings - how to remove expiration?

Tags: dropbox-api

I'm using v2 of the core API with HTTP directly, the method https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#sharing-modify_shared_link_settings. I have no problems changing the visiblity, password and expiration date of a link, but I can't see how to *remove* the expiration entirely.

I've tried

- not sending 'expires' at all in my request while changing other properties - no effect
- setting 'expires' to the the JSON literal null - no effect
- setting 'expires' to a time in the past - gives a 'invalid_settings' error
- setting 'expires' to an empty string - gives a "time data " " does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ'" error.

I'm kind of at a loss here, is there something obvious I'm missing?

Comment: [Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/205296726-modify-shared-link-removing-expiration-date ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per https://www.dropboxforum.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/205296726-modify-shared-link-removing-expiration-date , currently it is not possible to remove the expiration with the API. The workaround would be to set the expiration to a date very far in the future.

---

Update: This is now possible using the `remove_expiration` parameter on the [/sharing/modify_shared_link_settings](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#sharing-modify_shared_link_settings) endpoint.